# Routing public ipv6 traffic through openvpn tunnel

Tags: routing, openvpn, ipv6

What I'm trying to do is to route IPv6 traffic through a vpn tunnel. That way, I should be able to use IPv6 in a network that doesn't support IPv6.

I have a VPS which has an IPv6 block assigned. Part of this block I want to use for openvpn clients. The range I had in mind was `2001:db8::111:800:0/112` (prefix is anonymized), because openvpn only supports /64 and /112 as subnets.

IPv6 through the tunnel is already working, from the client, I can ping the server (`2001:db8::111:800:1`), and also interfaces on the server (`2001:db8::111:100:100` and `2001:db8:216:3dfa:f1d4:81c0`).

Though, when trying to ping google.com from the client, I get no response (ping timeout). In order to debug this issue, I have used tcpdump to capture traffic on the server, and I can see the ping packets going out, but no replies comming back. Adding log rules to ip6tables shows the same, packets going out, but nothing comming in.

I used an online traceroute tool which gets a timeout from my server. I also tried to set the ip directly on the interface, which does result in the ip (`2001:db8::111:800:1001`) to be reachable, so I think this is a routing problem.

I have enabled forwarding for ipv6 through `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding`. ip6tables has policy allow for all chains.

**My question is, what exactly is needed for linux to accept that packet for an ip that is not assigned to an interface and route it further?** Just a route that exists doesn't seem enough.

Here is the setup for my client and server. Please let it know if more information is needed.

**Client**

```
# ip -6 addresses
10: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 100
    inet6 2001:db8::111:800:1001/112 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# ip -6 routes
2001:db8::111:800:0/112 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256 
2000::/3 dev tun0  metric 1024
```

**Server**

```
# ip -6 address
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:db8:216:3dfa:f1d4:81c0/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft 86254sec preferred_lft 14254sec
    inet6 2001:db8::111:100:100/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 100
    inet6 2001:db8::111:800:1/112 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# ip -6 route
2001:db8::111:100:100 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
2001:db8::111:800:0/112 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256 
2001:db8::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 86194sec
default via fe80::230:48ff:fe94:d6c5 dev eth0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 1594sec
```

Comment: Possible you're looking for `POSTROUTING ... MASQUERADE` in the `nat` table. But I am not sure I understand completely. Are you trying to tunnel the IPv6 traffic? If so, do you have the respective facilities set up? Are `-p ipv6` packets allowed in the IPv4(!) rules?

Comment: Do you have the IP config of the router (on eth0)? Do you control the router? (can you add routes?)

Comment: Try using the iptables raw table `TRACE` target (maybe not so much here), `ip neighbour`, and `ip route get`. Also, please specify *who* is pinging `google.ca`.

Comment: Pinging google.com or goole.com.?

Comment: @totti google.com, was a typo

Comment: Sometimes you need to pay lot for typo errors :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to tell your router to use your server for this VPN subnet: the correct solution to your problem is to add a route on the router for the OpenVPN subnet.

If you can't do this because you can't touch the router, another solution is to setup a NDP proxy for the clients on the `eth0` link.

As you're using a VPS you probably can't add routes to the router: you probably have to use the second solution.

### Add a route for the subnet

The correct solution to your problem is to tell the router that
the VPN subnet must be routed via the OpenVPN server (this is
for Linux):

```
ip route add 001:db8::111:800::/112 via 2001:db8::111:100:100
```

You have to enable IPv6 forwarding on the server:

```
sysctl sys.net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

### NDP proxy

It seems the router is configured to send your whole IPv6 range on the `eth0` link: you can setup a NDP proxy.

You should see NDP requests on the `eth0` interface of the server for your OpenVPN subnet when trying to access the rest of internet from the client.

You need to enable IPv6 forwarding on the server as well
and NDP proxy:

sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp=1

#### subnet NDP proxy

The Linux kernel does not allow to add a NDP proxy for a subnet but only for individual IPs. You can use a daemon (such as
[ndppd](https://github.com/DanielAdolfsson/ndppd) to setup a NDP proxy for a whole subnet (never used it).

#### Per IP NDP proxy

Another solution is to can add a NDP proxy for each IPv6 of the VPN subnet:

```
for i in $(seq 0 65535) ; do
  ip neigh add proxy 2001:db8::111:800:$(printf %x $i) dev tun0
done
```

This should work as you have a compatatively small number of IPs in the OpenVPN subnet.

#### Dynamic NDP proxy with OpenVPN hooks

You should be able to use OpenVPN hooks to add NDP proxy dynamicaly.

Add hook in the OpenVPN server conf:

```
learn-address /etc/openvpn/learn-address
```

With the following `learn-address` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

action="$1"
addr="$2"

case "$action" in
    add | update)
        ip neigh replace proxy "$addr" dev tun0
        ;;
    delete)
        ip neigh del proxy "$addr" dev tun0
        ;;
esac
```

See this [thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.openvpn.devel/7607).

### Short answer

```
for i in $(seq 0 65535) ; do
  ip neigh add proxy 2001:db8::111:800:$(printf %x $i) dev tun0
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I now understand the problem. http://www.ipsidixit.net/2010/03/24/239/ contains more details about this.

Comment: I have the ip from the client as neighbour proxy. I have enabled sys.net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp, but I still cannot ping google.com. When I check the server, I see ndp solications packets comming in on eth0, but no advertisements going out.

Comment: After installing and setting up npd6 it suddenly works!