# OpenVPN with /112 IPv6 subnet, unable to route to eth0 and vice-versa

Tags: routing, openvpn, ipv6

I'm trying to set up an IPv6-enabled OpenVPN server. The provider only gave me a /64 subnet : `2a06:1700:1::640/64`.

Here is the OpenVPN configuration :

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun0
server-ipv6 2a06:1700:1::640:0/112
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
user nobody
group nogroup
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 80.67.169.12"
push "dhcp-option DNS 80.67.169.40"
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify crl.pem
tls-server
tls-auth tls-auth.key 0
```

Clients can get an IPv6 address, for example, my Android phone had `2a06:1700:1::640:1000`. But they can't access the IPv6 outside world. And they can't be accessed either.

I did set up `ndppd` :

```
proxy eth0 {
    router yes
    timeout 500   
    ttl 30000
    rule 2a06:1700:1::640:0/112 {
        auto
    }
 }
```

I used `tcpdump ip6 -i eth0` while pinging `2a06:1700:1::640:1000` from the outside :

```
03:22:05.510078 IP6 laptop > 2a06:1700:1::640:1000: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1390, length 64
03:22:06.519622 IP6 laptop > 2a06:1700:1::640:1000: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1391, length 64
03:22:07.527548 IP6 laptop > 2a06:1700:1::640:1000: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1392, length 64
03:22:08.515457 IP6 laptop > 2a06:1700:1::640:1000: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1393, length 64
```

Using `tcpdump ip6 -i tun0` shows nothing about that ping. And connections made from the OpenVPN client to the outside IPv6 world, let's say `ping ipv6.google` do appear in `tcpdump ip6 -i tun0` but not in `tcpdump ip6 -i eth0`. This looks like a routing problem, but I can't figure out what exactly.

**ip -6 route** :

```
2a06:1700:1::640:0/112 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256 
2a06:1700:1::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
default via 2a06:1700:1:: dev eth0  metric 1024
```

**route -6** :

```
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
::1/128                        ::                         U    256 0     0 lo
2a06:1700:1::640:0/112         ::                         U    256 1     0 tun0
2a06:1700:1::/64               ::                         U    256 0     1 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 1     0 eth0
::/0                           2a06:1700:1::              UG   1024 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1  1914 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   1     4 lo
2a06:1700:1::/128              ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
2a06:1700:1::640/128           ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
2a06:1700:1::640:0/128         ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
2a06:1700:1::640:1/128         ::                         Un   0   1    60 lo
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
fe80::250:56ff:fe96:7322/128   ::                         Un   0   1    62 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 5     0 eth0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 1     0 tun0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1  1914 lo
```

How can I make `eth0` and `tun0` talk to each other ?

Thank you very much !

*IPv6 addresses have been anonymized*

Comment: Solved using those `ip6tables` rules : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187867/172810